# Узнать время между датами

Tags: c++, время

Использую такую структуру и функцию для получения текущего системного времени

```
struct sysTimeStruct {
        int years;
        int months;
        int dayOfWeek;
        int dayNum;
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
    };

    void Time::sysTime(sysTimeStruct & c) {
        SYSTEMTIME sTime;
        GetLocalTime(&sTime);

        c.years = (int)sTime.wYear;
        c.months = (int)sTime.wMonth;
        c.dayOfWeek = (int)sTime.wDayOfWeek;
        c.dayNum = (int)sTime.wDay;
        c.hours = (int)sTime.wHour;
        c.minutes = (int)sTime.wMinute;
        c.seconds = (int)sTime.wSecond;
    }
```

А так же получаю дату с сайта в виде `2018-01-12 07-14-28`, и перевожу её в другую структуру

```
struct upTimeStruct {
        int years;
        int months;
        int day;
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
    };
```

Мне нужно вывести на экран время, которое прошло от `2018-01-12 07-14-28`, т.е. в итоге мне нужно вывести сообщение типа:

```
Прошло 2 дня 5 часов 12 минут 59 секунд.
```

Это можно сделать конвертируя обе даты в секунды, вычитать одну из другой, снова конвертировать обратно в календарное время..

Я, конечно, не эксперт, но мне кажется, что это будет работать довольно медленно. Какие есть ещё варианты?

Comment: именно конвертируйте в секунды (или что то поменьше). А то иначе могут быть разные неожиданности при переводе времени (зимнее/летнее)

Comment: всё будет нормально работать

Comment: Тогда каким способом лучше всего переводить дату в секунды?

Comment: [mktime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime)

Comment: чтобы быть кратким, пользуйтесь следующим руководствам https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h